# Dataset separator ? java

Tags: java, dataset

I would like to create a dataset that will ask java program to read it. I have ints and strings with some , ; :# .

I am thinking to use a combination of characters like $^!/ ?

So I was wondering if there is a professional way to separate fields?

More explanation:

If I have strings with all this characters between :

```
1- The weather is cold " , but etc. 
2- The weather ' is #: not cold! ; but etc. 
3- The weather! is hot# : but etc.
```

How can I add them to file so that I can read later ? using , won't work since the string already have , ?

2 downvoter, care to explain your downvote?

Comment: `String.split`? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Presumably this is in a file, right? Why use a combination of characters? Pick a character that is not contained in your data.

Comment: @Paul this is what I was planning to do , but I get 2 downvote !

Comment: Do you need just each line or each token on each line?

Comment: @Paul I need all the data in the line including comma etc

Comment: Look at the `BufferedReader` class. That has a `readLine` method.

Comment: [You can probably use `readLine()` method of this object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Comment: That sounds familiar, @AJG85 :)

Comment: Lol, I had to look up how to make the link so you beat me to it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by professional way but **comma** is a general accepted standard and there are many open source libraries that can parse **CSV** files.

Comment: @tnaser Then pick a character that is guaranteed to not be present in the data or ESCAPE the comma in values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the dataset, then can you escape any instances of your separator character before you import.  e.g. `"Field 1", "Field 2, and a comma", "Field 3 with escaped speechmarks \"inside\" the actual delimeters"`?

This is how the CSV standard is done, that way you can make use of CSV parsers that already exist.

Comment: What if I have string with "" ''  inside ?

Comment: My example did - you escape the " symbol with a backslash e.g. `"This is a field which contains \" symbols"`

Comment: won't this means more time to process all string and check when we need to add \ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a well-known, easily parsable format like XML or JSON. There are plenty of parsers for these two formats, in any language. And the rules to escape special characters are standard and well-defined.

Comment: OP is asking about a way to parse existing data. Your answer is completely change the source data to a more complicated format and use third party parsing libraries for said format. That's somewhat like telling someone to get a car when they ask how to fix their bicycle.

Comment: No, that's not what the OP asks. He asks what format he should use to separate fields that may have arbitrary characters in it. Read the question again.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that all he really needs is a line reader for a flat text file. Why add unnecessary complexity?

Comment: Because IMHO, it's not complexity, it's simplicity. Rather than defining a proprietary format, with proprietary escaping rules, and a proprietary parser, you use a standard format, with already established rules and parsers that handle all the cases (special characters, i18n, newlines, etc.)

Comment: I'd agree that's certainly better than rolling your own parsing framework and format but to me the context suggested this was closer to homework than something of that caliber.